# Combining knockout binding with selectOrDie

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to be able to just apply a knockout binding `selectOrDie` on a select element to apply selectOrDie generically.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.selectOrDie = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
        // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here

        $(element).selectOrDie({
            onChange: function() {
                console.log(element);
            }
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
        // and again whenever any observables/computeds that are accessed change
        // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
        console.log($(element).siblings('span .sod_label').text());

    }
};
```

I don't know how to set it up in a way that the changes registered by selectOrDie triggers an update on the binding. Or is there a better approach?

This is the select element, nothing particular:

```
            <select data-bind="selectOrDie: $data" data-custom-class="w60">
                <option>10</option>
                <option>20</option>
                <option>30</option>
                <option>50</option>
                <option>Alle</option>
            </select>
```

How can I make a knockout binding that generically applies [selectOrDie](http://vst.mn/selectordie/) to the element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach to this is to use the existing [options](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) binding provided by knockout to get the two-way data binding goodness between some array or observable array in your view model and your `select` element.

Then create a separate binding handler that allows to apply the *selectOrDie* widget to the same `select` element. Here is a *selectOrDie* binding handler I created earlier:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.selectOrDie = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // apply selectOrDie widget to select element
        $(element).selectOrDie(valueAccessor());

        var subsription, options = allBindings()["options"];

        // check if bounded collection from "options" binding is observable array
        if(options && ko.isObservable(options) && "push" in options){
            // ensure changes to bounded collection update selectOrDie widget
            subscription = options.subscribe(function(){
                $(element).selectOrDie("update");
            });
        }

        // register disposal to clean up after dom node is removed
         ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            subscription.dispose();
            $(element).selectOrDie("destroy");
        });
    }
};
```

Now this binding handler in combination with the existing `options` binding will allow you to do this:

```
<select data-bind="options: myArray, value: myValue, selectOrDie: { }">
</select>
```

Notice that I have passed an empty object into the `selectOrDie` binding, you can also pass an object containing valid [configuration options](http://vst.mn/selectordie/) instead like this:

```
<select data-bind="options: myArray, value: myValue, selectOrDie: {customClass: 'someclass' }">
</select>
```

Check this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AnishPatelUk/ne7gdt7o/).

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question write (apologies if I don't :)) ... you are trying to reflect changes on the DOM back to the observable that is bound to element. If that is the case then all you need to do is add the code that changes the value of the observable on the plugin's change event, in your case in the "onChange" callback. so the modification would resemble

```
 $(element).selectOrDie({
            onChange: function() {
                var value = valueAccessor();
            value($(element).val()); //extract the value you wish to set to the observable here
            }
        });
```

I have a created a teared down version of your code without the plugin here https://jsfiddle.net/0Ljy13c0/4/

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping a jQuery plugin with a custom binding is fairly simple. You must set up a way of listening for changes in the `init`. This is where you will apply the selected value to your observable. In the `update` you will need to update the view with the current value of your observable. `update` will run every time the observable changes. If you don't implement the `update` method then if you modify the observable from somewhere else, this change won't be reflected by the select.

Looks like SelectOrDie provides you with an `onChange` function to get changes *from* the `<select>` and an `'update'` option to apply changes *to* the `<select>`.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.selectOrDie = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).selectOrDie({
            onChange: function() {
                var value = valueAccessor(); //get observable
                value($(element).val()); //write to observable
            }
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); //get current observable value
        $(element).val(value); //update selected value
        $(element).selectOrDie('update'); //inform SoD that something has changed
    }
};
```